# how to add gestureRecognizer for manually created object?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I have manually created an object (File -> New -> NewClass -> UITableViewCell) and added .xib to it. 
Created cell have several labels, see the picture [image: created Cell]

After that I use this object in other class

```
myCell * showHere;
NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myCell" owner:self options:nil];
showHere = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
```

How can I add gestureRecognizer for UIlabel on this cell?

I have tried this:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                           initWithTarget:self 
                                           action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;
[showHere.monday addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

and this

```
    -(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
NSLog(@"label has pressed");
```

}

I need to catch action by pressing on single label. Is it possible?
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Add `YourLabel.userinteractionEnabled = YES` after

`UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                           initWithTarget:self 
                                           action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;`

To enable touches to your Label

Good Luck

Comment: is the cell receive action in didselectrow ??

Comment: Yes. I , even, tried to create recognizer in cell class, but it doesn`t work too...

Comment: I`ve done it! I have added recognize method in cellForRowAtIndexPath